# Unusual SQL query execution behavior

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase-15.7

I am optimizing my SQL script and when i tried to run it i noticed the following;

1. Script full query execution (end to end) took more than 2hours to complete
2. Script query-by-query execution took 44 mins to complete

I'm just wondering, why is my script full query execution took so much runtime than the same script query-by-query execution? Is there some hidden process happening inside the DB? Or any special case for those execution scenario?

Tried to ask our DBA, but he seem to avoid the question maybe he doesn't know. I hope ill got some answers/leads here.

Thanks

Comment: Not very sure however it seems when you are executing them one by one - its part of multiple statements whereas when you execute them all in one shot, its all part of same batch. Can you try putting go statement after each SQL query and run them all in once or separately and see if there is still execution time difference. I suspect this to be a logging issue. Possibly, you have trunc log on chkpt enabled for this database.

Comment: enable showplan and stats/io (`set showplan on`, `set statistics io on` *and* `go`) before running the queries and once done review the two sets of output ... the one-long-batch-of-sql has to guess at statistics for each qeury while the each-query-in-a-different-batch can benefit from stats generated by previous batches ... query plans and io stats should highliight these differences if this is the case; another step to consider is monitoring the queries while they run ... key objective being to watch for excessive blocking and/or temporary suspension of the query due to the log filling up

Comment: the title `'DBA'` encompasses a handful of skills ... day-to-day (Business As Usual - BAU) tasks like adding disk space and users, resetting passwords, following a checklist provided by someone else ... SQL coding (easy and complex) ... P&T (performance and tuning) of queries and/or server configs and/or overall processing ... monitoring and infrastructure support (DB software testing, upgrades, migrations) ... applcation-focused vs production-system-focused ... and then you get into specialized stuff (eg, replication, DR/backup/failover, etc); most DBAs have a subset of these skills